# Is there a way to directly compute maximum of a sum of several Gaussian functions?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, machine-learning, gauss-sums

I have a problem which goes as follows.  I am trying to predict the value of a variable $x$.  I also have a set of measurements (the actual context is an image) $x^i$.  I know from some training examples that my measurements are able to predict the value of $x$ with varying accuracy;  for example, I have that $x \approx N(x^i + \mu^i, \sigma^i)$ for each measurement.  That is, the *difference* between $x$ and $x^i$ gives a normal distribution which I know the mean and variance of.

So, given that I have several measurements $x^i$ each with their own Gaussian predication of $x$, I want to find the most likely value of $x$.  My questions are:

1) Am I correct in thinking that the best approach here is to sum the Gaussian PDFs and find the maximum?

And if so:

2) Is there a way to directly compute the maximum of a sum of Gaussian functions?

If I am thinking about this correctly I think it is similar to a Gaussian Mixture Model, although this has yet to help me.

Any reassurance and general advice on my approach would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should not be adding the pdfs together; rather you should (assuming the measurements are independent) be taking the product i.e. add the pdfs on the log scale. A good starting point for any model is to write down the likelihood if you have one; in this case the observations are just a string of Gaussians. Also, you probably want $x^i \sim N(x + \mu^i, \sigma^i)$ which are conditionally independent given $x$; you should model $x$ first (or regard it as an unknown constant) and then the distribution of the $x^i$'s given $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem of estimation. Just a correction: the mean of the error should be zero (as you know the mean, you can substract this value from the estimation).

I think this problem is well explained in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory#Unknown_constant_in_additive_white_Gaussian_noise)

Hope it helps and no doubt in asking any doubt about it.